# Staggered for statements

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have [this](http://jsfiddle.net/G28dd/) code<sup>JSFiddle</sup>, and when you hover over the cells, the column changes colour, however, when you move your mouse to another cell you can see that the colour seems to revert in a staggered pattern, does anyone have any idea why this is happening, I don't want a lecture on how horrible my code is please.

Code that handles the un-highlighting:

```
tables[i].onmouseout = function(e){
    var target;
    if(e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'span') target = e.target.parentNode;
    else if(e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'td') target = e.target;
    if(!target || target.innerHTML == '&nbsp;') return;
    target = document.getElementsByClassName('hcell');
    for(var i = 0; i < target.length; i++){
        target[i].className = target[i].className.replace(/\bhcell\b/,'');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in your onmouseover logic, you are adding the hcell class a dozen times and then later you remove only one of them, a short test in your fiddle resulted in this:

```
<td class="letter hcell hcell hcell hcell hcell hcell hcell hcell hcell hcell hcell hcell hcell hcell hcell hcell hcell hcell hcell hcell hcell hcell hcell hcell"><span class="tblsup">2</span>D</td>
```

Consider making your life a lot easier using jQuery for this.